# Disabling browser cache when using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

Why do you usually need to disable the browser cache when sending requests via AJAX?

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* to, but it's for the same reason as any other browser cache disabling...you want to prevent the browser from using a previously fetched response...in other words you want the latest the server has to offer.

*Usually* cache headers from the server suffice, and you don't need to do much else, in *other* caes however...specifically, IE is the reason *most* of the time, it likes the cache the hell out of a response, requiring a query-string cache breaker to reliably get an non-cached response.

Comment: You mean attaching something like "time=2011-17-4-12-30" to the requested URL to break the caching mechanisms? No other solutions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote little bookmarklet which prevents AJAX cache. Try it. Let me know if it helped.
http://marklets.com/Prevent+AJAX+from+being+cached.aspx

Text version:
javascript:(function(){if%20(typeof%20jQuery%20==%20'undefined')%20{%20var%20jQ%20=%20document.createElement('script');%20jQ.type%20=%20'text/javascript';%20jQ.onload=runthis;%20jQ.src%20=%20'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js';%20document.body.appendChild(jQ);%20}%20else%20{%20runBookmarklet();%20}%20%20%20function%20runBookmarklet()%20{%20$.ajaxSetup({cache:%20false});%20}})();